# Javascript, Websockets and XMPP client. How to make them work together?

Tags: javascript, websocket, xmpp, ejabberd

I need a "Hello world!" example, that demonstrates how to use `websocket`s and `ejabberd` in combination. So, this is where I am:

1. I have `ejabberd` installed and running
2. I have two accounts: "user1" and "user2" with passwords "123"
3. I'm able to run `psi plus` client under both users and I can send
   messages to myself
4. I know from the official site of `ejabberd` that it supports `websockets`
5. I know there is popular plugin `Strophe.js` that many people use to
   connect to `ejabberd`

and this is the list of problems:

1. I do not know what is the right way to set `ejabberd` configuration
   (I guess, I installed a fresh version of ejabberd and its
   configuration is located in `ejabberd.yml`)
2. I do not know whether I should make specific configuration
   of `Apache` server (proxies, rewrites etc. - in many forums 
   I've seen some examples that involve such manipulations)
3. I do not know what `Javascript` or `C++` or `Python` code will
   match this puzzle, so that I could make a simple
   `connect` to or `send` a message

Well, I spent two days and completely in vain. Whatever configuration settings I have and whatever code I have, I always get from FF a message:

```
Firefox can't establish connection to the server 
at ws://localhost:5280/http-ws
```

And, yes, I edited `ejabberd.yml`, so that it has these lines:

```
requests_handlers:
   "http-ws/": ejabberd_http_ws
```

I also edited apache configs, so that I have:

```
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPass /http-ws/ http://localhost:5280/http-ws/
ProxyPassReverse /http-ws/ http://localhost:5280/http-ws/
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule http-ws/ http://localhost:5280/http-ws/
```

Indeed, I restarted both apache and ejabberd. And in my code I have:

```
var SocketUrl = 'ws://localhost:5280/http-ws'
...other standard stuff
```

I guess, I tried dozens * dozens of combinations, but none of them works. So, I need a step-by-step instruction that will answer to these three questions:

1. How to set `ejabberd`
2. How to set `Apache`
3. How primitive example (in `JavaScript`) should look like

**EDIT**

This configuration I have now:

```
1. ejabberd.yml:

...
hosts:
 - "localhost"
....
listen:
....
  -
    port: 5280
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
     "/http-ws": ejabberd_http_ws
    web_admin: true
    http_poll: true
    http_bind: true
....

acl:
  admin:
    user:
     - "admin": "localhost"
access:
 configure:
    admin: allow

2. apache2.conf

<Directory />
  AllowOverride All
  Allow From All
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/site>
  AllowOverride All
  Allow From All
</Directory>

3. apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/site

    <Directory /var/www/site>
       Options  +Indexes +MultiViews
    </Directory>
    ProxyRequests off
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
    ProxyPass /http-ws/ http://127.0.0.1:5280/http-ws/
    ProxyPassReverse /http-ws/ http://127.0.0.1:5280/http-ws/
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule /http-ws/http://127.0.0.1:5280/http-ws/

  ...
```

And finally this is the code I have:

```
window.onload = function(){
     var SocketUrl = 'ws://localhost:5280/http-ws/';
     var connection = null;
     function onConnect(status){
       if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNECTING) {
     alert('Strophe is connecting.');
       } else if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNFAIL) {
     alert('Strophe failed to connect.');
       } else if (status == Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTING) {
     alert('Strophe is disconnecting.');
       } else if (status == Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTED) {
     alert('Strophe is disconnected.');
       } else if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
     alert('Strophe is connected.');
       }
    }
    var button = document.getElementById("connect");
    button.onclick = function(){
      connection = new Strophe.Connection(SocketUrl);
      var jid = document.getElementById("jid").value;
      var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
      connection.connect(jid, pass, onConnect);
    }
  }
```

As a result, while running this example I always get these alerts:

```
Strophe is connecting
Strophe failed to connect
Strophe is disconnected
```

And in the console I see this error message:

```
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:5280/http-ws/
```

**Ejabberd log**

This is what I have in `ejabberd` log:

```
2015-08-20 12:52:40.558 [error] <0.448.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.448.0> with 0 neighbours crashed with reason: call to undefined function ejabberd_http_ws:process([], {request,'GET',[<<"http-ws">>],[{nokey,<<>>}],{<<>>,<<>>},undefined,<<"en-US">>,<<>>,{{0,0,0,0,...},...},...})
2015-08-20 12:52:40.559 [error] <0.326.0> Supervisor ejabberd_http_sup had child undefined started with {ejabberd_http,start_link,undefined} at <0.448.0> exit with reason undef in context child_terminated
```

I think, I should stress this line from the log:

```
call to undefined function ejabberd_http_ws
```

I tried to enable this module under `module` section in `ejabberd.yml` like:

```
modules:
   ...
   mod_http_ws: {}
```

which I think should work, if [documentation](http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/configuration/#modhttpws) is not lying. However, in this case I'm unable to restart `ejabberd` and in its log file I now see this message:

```
 initialization was aborted because a module start failed
```

**Package**

This is some information about `ejabberd` package that I installed simply with the command:

```
$ apt-get -y install ejabberd
```

So, `$ dpkg -s ejabberd` returns

```
Package: ejabberd
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: net
Installed-Size: 6405
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 14.07-4ubuntu1
Provides: xmpp-server
Depends: adduser, erlang-base (>= 1:15.b) | erlang-abi-17.0, erlang-asn1 (>= 1:17.3-dfsg), erlang-base (>= 1:17.3-dfsg) | erlang-base-hipe (>= 1:17.3-dfsg), erlang-crypto (>= 1:17.3-dfsg), erlang-inets (>= 1:17.3-dfsg), erlang-mnesia (>= 1:17.3-dfsg), erlang-odbc (>= 1:17.3-dfsg), erlang-public-key (>= 1:17.3-dfsg), erlang-ssl (>= 1:17.3-dfsg), erlang-syntax-tools (>= 1:17.3-dfsg), openssl, ucf, debconf (>= 0.5) | debconf-2.0, erlang-lager, erlang-jiffy, erlang-p1-cache-tab, erlang-p1-iconv, erlang-p1-mysql, erlang-p1-pam, erlang-p1-pgsql, erlang-p1-sip, erlang-p1-stringprep, erlang-p1-stun, erlang-p1-tls, erlang-p1-utils, erlang-p1-xml, erlang-p1-yaml, erlang-p1-zlib, erlang-xmlrpc
Recommends: ejabberd-contrib
Suggests: libunix-syslog-perl, imagemagick | graphicsmagick-imagemagick- compat
Conflicts: ejabberd-mod-shared-roster-ldap
Conffiles:
 /etc/default/ejabberd 49352468a39da545ad13586af05877f9
 /etc/ejabberd/inetrc a8de3c20d2ac990c8f319907b340d6a2
 /etc/init.d/ejabberd 58aa53c895ae2250e80ea16769db0417
 /etc/logrotate.d/ejabberd d2a0a63e544aabfb797f718471c6d173
 /etc/ufw/applications.d/ejabberd abc263fcde39ff65e9b5722be81db8ff
Description: distributed, fault-tolerant Jabber/XMPP server written in Erlang
 ejabberd is a distributed, fault-tolerant Jabber/XMPP server written in Erlang.
```

And `$ service ejabberd status` returns

```
● ejabberd.service - LSB: Starts ejabberd jabber server
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/ejabberd)
Active: active (exited) since Thu 2015-08-20 13:32:27 PDT; 12h ago
 Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 12701 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/ejabberd stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 13716 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/ejabberd start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 20 13:32:22 ubuntu ejabberd[13716]: /usr/sbin/ejabberdctl: 156: /etc/eja...d
Aug 20 13:32:22 ubuntu ejabberd[13716]: /usr/sbin/ejabberdctl: 157: /etc/eja...d
Aug 20 13:32:22 ubuntu ejabberd[13716]: /usr/sbin/ejabberdctl: 158: /etc/eja...d
Aug 20 13:32:22 ubuntu ejabberd[13716]: /usr/sbin/ejabberdctl: 159: /etc/eja...d
Aug 20 13:32:22 ubuntu ejabberd[13716]: /usr/sbin/ejabberdctl: 160: /etc/eja...d
Aug 20 13:32:22 ubuntu ejabberd[13716]: /usr/sbin/ejabberdctl: 161: /etc/eja...d
Aug 20 13:32:22 ubuntu ejabberd[13716]: /usr/sbin/ejabberdctl: 163: /etc/eja...d
Aug 20 13:32:22 ubuntu ejabberd[13716]: /usr/sbin/ejabberdctl: 164: /etc/eja...d
Aug 20 13:32:27 ubuntu ejabberd[13716]: done.
Aug 20 13:32:27 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started LSB: Starts ejabberd jabber server.
```

Comment: I will start a really BIG bounty tomorrow, since I need a step-by-step fresh and deep instruction on this topic. So, hurry up to get some huge karma :)

Comment: By the way, if you know how to implement the similar thing in `Python` or `C++` and can share some working code, I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ejabberd supports websockets from version 15.03 onwards - which solved the answer above.

This has nothing to do with python or C++ - the puzzle is simply about configuring Ejabberd to support websockets, and optionally using a proxy to handle websockets traffic.

Under the ejabjjerd.yml section, module: ejabberd_http  add

```
request_handlers:
  "/http-ws": ejabberd_http_ws
```

This will then be available at port 5280:/http-ws

If this is not convenient, you can proxy from port 80 using apache or nginx.

For nginx, within the virtual host you need something like this, where JABBERIP is the ip address of ejabberd.  This proxies the websocket connection from the standard http port 80 through to ejabberd, with the connection configured to handle websockets.

```
location /http-ws/ {
 proxy_pass http://JABBERIP:5280;  // this is 
 proxy_http_version 1.1;
 proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
 proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

you might also need to adjust websocket settings in ejabberd.yml - I put these at the top of the file..

```
websocket_ping_interval: 60
websocket_timeout: 86400
```

Setting up strophe is beyond the scope of this answer, but the key bit is setting up the connection to use websockets IF the browser supports this. The following snippit is from an angularjs app - though you get the idea... the SocketUrl is public location of the /http-ws location as shown above.. this could be the :5280 version or the version as proxied to port 80.

```
        if (window.WebSocket && (passwd != 'undefined' && passwd != null)) {
            $this.connection = new Strophe.Connection($this.SocketUrl);
            $this.connection.connect(user_info.username+'@'+$this.jabberUrl, passwd, $this.onConnect.bind($this));
        } else {
            UserService.getJabberData().then(function (response) {
                var jabber = response.data;
                $this.connection = new Strophe.Connection($this.BOSHUrl);
                $this.connection.attach(jabber.jid, jabber.sid, jabber.rid, $this.onConnect.bind($this));
            });
        }
```

There are also xmpp libraries for python and other languages - though if you are looking at building an app to run in a web browser, strophe is an excellent choice.

Comment: "the SocketUrl is public location of the /http-ws location" . Can you, please, elaborate a little bit on this? How can `SocketUrl` look like? Something like `ws://host:port/http-ws` or `http://host:port/http-ws`? I'm asking this, because I've seen multiple variants in different examples, but all of the examples were out of the context (not a word was said about ejabberd.yml)

Comment: And should not it be `proxy_pass http://JABBERIP:5280/http-ws/` ? I'm asking this because in many examples with `Apache` I've seen something like `RewritePass http-bind/ http://JABBERIP:5280/http-bind/ ; RewriteRule http-bind/ http://JABBERIP:5280/http-bind/`

Comment: Using my example the location of the socketurl for your client application would be ws://host:port/http-ws - if you used the proxy this would be via port 80 so you don't need to specify port. If you are addressing the ejabberd server directly you need to include port.  The main benefit of proxying port 80 is that it will be more supported for people behind proxies and corporate firewalls etc.

Comment: In my setup, proxy_pass http://JABBERIP:5280/http-ws works fine without trailing slash.. with apache ymmv

Comment: Would you be so kind to look at the updated version of my question? Thanks!

Comment: Will have a proper look in a while - but note that in your code you are not going via Apache - by using :5280 you are addressing ejabberd websocket handler directly. That is actually a good idea initially, get things working there before introducing apache.  I suggest you add the settings I offered at the top of your ejabberd.yml.. websocket_ping_interval: 60
websocket_timeout: 86400

Comment: Also, is that an abridged version of your ejabberd.yml or the entire file - if it is the entire file I think that might be your problem..

Comment: As for your last question, it is a tiny part of `ejabberd.yml`. All the rest is just left unchanged (as it was by default after `ejabberd` installation). Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, don't you know why in `ejabberd` log I can have this error message: `call to undefined function ejabberd_http_ws` ? Thanks!

Comment: BTW. I did it - `websocket_ping_interval: 60`,  `websocket_timeout: 86400` , but still in `ejabberd.log` I have this error message - `call to undefined function ejabberd_http_ws`

Comment: I think you are close to an answer :) Clearly ejabberd is not loading the websockets module..  Can you confirm what version of ejabberd you are running / how did you install, from source, package etc? ejabberdctl status would be helpful..

Comment: Yes, I also feel that I'm very close to the solution :)) I will post this additional information in a minute

Comment: I updated my question. Please, have a look. Many thanks!

Comment: And btw I have 14.07 version of `ejabberd`

Comment: Think that might be the issue - looks like websocket support added in 15.03 https://www.ejabberd.im/node/24818 - I think you should try upgrading to latest version, 15.07

Comment: Run ejabberdctl status  to be sure of the version you are running - and if this is < 15.03 then you don't have websocket support....

Comment: You are absolutely right. If only documentation was a bit more precise on this point. Just one comment under `mod_http_ws` that it is supported only in version higher than 15.03 will save me two days. It's a very, very poor documentation. Thanks for sharing your thoughts!

Comment: Thank you for your great help! I owe you!